# CSS is not updating in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the text color of a header but the value is not being updated. Any idea whats going wrong?
Here is my code:

```
.content
{
    text-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Child theme? where exactly did you update that code? you can always look in your console which CSS file is being loaded and then update it.

Comment: i have selected and activated the theme in wordpress and i am trying to change the text color. i have open the css in wordpad and i ll make the changes and upload in server. but its not get updating

Comment: Make sure the file is actually loaded -AFTER- all the other CSS files!

Answer (score 2):

It's not `text-color:blue;` it's `color:blue` property to change the color of the text/font.

Use

```
.content
{
 color:blue;
}
```

Will work for you. Refer [this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
.content
{
color:blue!important;
}
```

Remember headers are styled under **h** tag.

```
h1 {
color:blue!important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>I'm the Header now</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.content
{
color:blue;
}
```

There is no such (you above said) css to change the text color